# Getting the time of USB connection

Tags: python, windows, powershell, usb, regedit

When someone is connecting a USB device into a computer, the computer writes its properties into the registry under the ENUM\USB Hive.
I know that in order to get the time of connection i can just right click > export the key and save it as a txt file.
My question is:
Is there a way to automate it? with python / powershell or any other scripting language?
I wasn't able to find a way.
[Picture of the timestamp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0P8EJ.png)

Comment: You can use this article as a starting point: https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/window-registry. This is definitely doable, and shouldn't be too difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the register could be a bit tricky, depending on the OS you are working on. But, if working in python, you could just monitor the USB devices and save the timestamp every time you detect a connection event.

You could do it this way, with [USBMonitor](https://pypi.org/project/usb-monitor/):
Install the library

```
pip install usb-monitor
```

Write a script like this:

```
from usbmonitor import USBMonitor
from time import time

# Define the `on_connect` callback to get you the timestamp
on_connect = lambda device_id, device_info: print("Connected USB device:", time())

# Create the Monitor instance
monitor = USBMonitor()

# Start the daemon
monitor.start_monitoring(on_connect=on_connect, on_disconnect=None)

# ... Rest of your code ...
```

It should work for you independently of the OS you are running.